# Split long String In C# to Array, return first element empty?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, split

I have a log file with some lines:

```
test123 (random text..)
test123 (random text..)
test123 (random text..)
```

I want to convert it into an array, so I did the following:

```
string[] myArray = logFileText.Replace("test123", "#test123").Split("#");
```

This work fine except for the fact that the first element in myArray is empty.. any idea how to solve this?

Note: cannot use Environment.NewLine, it does not work on this file for some reason..

Comment: `Split('#', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`

Comment: although this is a very odd thing to do, you should work out why newline doesnt work, its almost certainly becuase you are on windows (nl = crlf) and the file is from non windows (nl = nl). Just do Split('\n');

Comment: *I want to convert it into an array* - use File.ReadAllLines instead of File.ReadAllText

Comment: @pm100 *Just do Split('\n');* - but if adopting that as policy, I'd worry what about orphaned \r in this/other files...

Answer (score 0):

As *@pm100* said, this is the answer:

```
Split('#', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Comment: But is it though? What if you have  ## elsewhere and you want to keep *that* empty one.  RemoveEmptyEntires clobbers all of the blanks, but you *did cause the "problem" yourself* by actively putting a delimiter at the start of the string, so it's expected that everything before the first delimiter (empty string) is returned..

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `.Skip(1)` to the end of your code:

```
string[] myArray = logFileText.Replace("test123", "#test123").Split("#").Skip(1).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the file line-by-line. This should work

```
  var filePath = "D:\\MyLogfile.txt";

        var fileContents = File.ReadAllLines(filePath); //Reads line by line
        if (fileContents.Length > 0) //If file has any lines/content
        {
            var myFileContents = fileContents.Skip(1); //Skips the first row

            foreach (var fileLine in myFileContents) //Process line by line
            {
                
            }
        }
```